# Turn this into a skeptic-proof proof

Tags: prime-numbers, logarithms

I'm stuck on this question its from my math class.
I appreciate your help.

> **Turn this into a skeptic-proof proof.**
>
> Suppose that there were only finitely many primes.
> Then I'll use that assumption to create a compression scheme
> for arbitrary numbers.
> Indeed, given $n$, I can express it as a product of primes,
> so  $$n = 2^{v_2(n)} \cdot 3^{v_3(n)} \cdot 5^{v_5(n)} \cdots P^{v_P(n)}$$
> where $P$ is the largest prime.
> Now my compression for n is the array
> $$(v_2(n), v_3(n),...v_P(n))$$
> Crudely, let me convince that the compression uses fewer bits
> than just communicating or storing $n$.
> The worst case scenario for the size of $v_2(n)$ would be
> $n$ having no other prime factors, so $v_2(n)$ could be as large
> as $\log_2 (n)$ and I might need $\log_2 \log_2 (n)$ bits to store it.
> No other $v_p(n)$ could be even that big.  So the total number
> of bits I'll need is bounded by $N \log_2 \log_2 (n)$ where $N$ is
> the total number of primes.  But it usually requires $\log_2 (n)$
> bits to store a number, and if  $n$  is large enough
> $\log_2 n$ is much larger that  $N \log_2 \log_2 (n)$.

Comment: `Suppose that there were only finitely many primes` In the extreme, suppose that there was only one $N=1$ prime $P=2$. How would you rewrite the above in that case, and what precisely would be the point being made?

Comment: What is the purpose of this proof? On the one hand, it sounds like an incomplete proof by contradiction. On the other hand, from a false assumption you can prove anything. Are you trying to prove there are infinitely many primes, or is there a different goal?

Comment: Interesting idea.You could iterate repeatedly, compressing the compressed code for the compressed code for..... Intuitively that seems to imply that we should be able to encode an arbitrarily large set of numbers with just 1000 bits, but 1000 bits can only distinguish $2^{1000}$ different values. Perhaps someone can flesh this out.